# project in hand gesture volume control system

Tags: mediapipe

i want to download mediapipe version 0.8.3.1 on python 3.7 64 bit but that version of media pipe doesn't show up ... is this version is not in implementation anymore or which version of mediapiepe shall I use . I'm new to all this and trying to do project for hand gesture volume control system but I'm getting errors because of wrong version of mediapipe

i try to do with different version of mediapipe